# Can't start Emacs with Prelude (Windows)

Tags: windows, emacs, emacs-prelude

I successfully installed Emacs and Prelude on my Windows 10 machine. I had the following error during the setup that was fixed by adding Emacs to the path:

```
Emacs not found. Skipping byte-compilation.
```

While the above issue was resolved (see comments) and Prelude finally found Emacs during installation, when I run `emacs` or `runemacs` commands, vanilla Emacs starts. Prelude is ignored.
When I try to start server using `emacs --daemon`, all I see is the "Starting Emacs daemon." message and no other prelude-related loading messages.

How do I make Emacs start with Prelude?

I have no problems running Emacs with Prelude on Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

Comment: Put the location of Emacs in your `PATH`?

Comment: That fixed the issue with Prelude skipping byte-compilation. Thanks! Still, Prelude is being ignored when I start it with "emacs" or "runemacs" commands. "emacs --daemon" command only prints "Starting Emacs daemon.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl` installed Prelude in `.emacs.d` folder under my user directory which is also set to be my home directory -  `C:\Users\me`.

The problem was that there was another instance of `.emacs.d` configs in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming`. The latter was the default one. I added it to the `PATH`, moved Emacs folder (not sure if that was needed at all) to the`C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming` as well.

Now I could run `emacs` command that opened Emacs w/ Prelude, however, this isn't my preferred way. I still couldn't start daemon server because my input to "Continue connection?" question wasn't registered. The fix is described here -https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/emacs-daemon-hangs-on-first-run-on-emacs-25-2